# SQLiteException unknown error (code 0 SQLITE_OK): Native could not read blob slot

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, sqldelight

I see the following error when retrieving data from [sqldelight database](https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight), and it only happens if the retrieved data is relatively big.

> ***android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException · unknown error (code 0***
> ***SQLITE_OK): Native could not read blob slot CursorWindow.java:-2***

If the issue is that the query hits the operation size limit, how can we bypass this issue?

Comment: Could you provide us with your SQL queries? ( daos and other db related classes would be appreciated also ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Suspected there might be something wrong with your SQL query, but it seems alright

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html)
There is a 1MB limit per operation. So I guess that's the memory limit for one SQL query. The limit is due to the SQLite API interacting with sqlite out-of-process over the Binder/Parcel IPC system. The same limit applies for values within a Bundle (Intent extras, for instance).

you might also find some data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406429/cursor-size-limit-in-android-sqlitedatabase) ?